# re.error with Python 3.9.6 / Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python, parsing, python-re

I am trying to remove unwanted characters from a text (Commission.txt) using this:

```
File = open("/Applications/Python 3.9/Comission.txt",encoding="Latin-1")
Commission=File.read()
CommissionClean = re.sub(r'(Ñ)(Ó)(Ò)(xCA)(xca)([*\])','',Commission)
```

But receive the following error message:

```
 raise source.error("unterminated character set",
re.error: unterminated character set at position 20
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show a minimal, representative example of Commission.txt and the output you want? Error is pretty self-explanatory: `\]` escapes the `]`, so you have an unterminated character set. Remove the `\\` or escape it.

Comment: The backslash escapes the following character so that it is interpreted as literally this character without the special meaning in a regex. Write two backslashes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` makes the following `]` part of the character set, rather than being a member *of* the character set. As such, the parser also includes `)` in the set, and it is still waiting to see the closing `]` when the string ends.

You need to escape the backslash itself to make it part of the character set.

```
CommissionClean = re.sub(r'(Ñ)(Ó)(Ò)(xCA)(xca)([*\\])','',Commission)
```

This is above and beyond the use of a raw string literal, which prevents the backslashes from being used to define the string literal that the regex parser sees.

Answer (score 0):

`[*\]` should likely be `[\*\\]` or `\[*\]`